# Does SeleniumWebdrive change focus on element when using jQuery to locate an element?

Tags: c#, jquery, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

**Background:**

Been using Selenium 2.0 (WebDriver), and understand that the focus moves to elements when locating them, like so:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#foo"));
element.Click();
```

I also know we can do powerful things if jQuery is on the page under test (way cool):

```
IJavaScriptExecutor scriptExecutor = ((IJavascriptExecutor)driver);
scriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("$('#foo')[0].click();";
IWebElement hiddenElement = scriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("return $('#my_dynamic_element')[0]");
hiddenElement.Click;   // found ya!
```

**Question:**

Does Selenium's WebDriver (specifically .NET flavor) fire a focus while it's converting the `.ExecuteScript()` result into `IWebElement`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe so, and here is a test I setup to test this:

I created the following html page that contains a script that will change the class name when an element get focus:

```html
<script>
  function ChangeClass(theName, theClass)
  {
      document.getElementById(theName).className=theClass;
  }
</script>
<input type="text" class="notFocused" onfocus="ChangeClass('textfieldOne', 'focused');"    id="textfieldOne" />
```

When the field gets focus, it will change the class name.

Then, I can run the following WebDriver test that retrieves an element using the IJavaScriptExecutor, and then check to see if the class name was changed to indicate that the element was focused:

```cs
IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("test.html");

IJavaScriptExecutor scriptExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver;
IWebElement element = (IWebElement)scriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("return document.getElementById('textfieldOne');");

Assert.AreEqual("focused", element.GetAttribute("class"));
```

The assert fails, which tells me that focus was not set.

Comment: Nice approach.  What happens with your test when you provide more than one input field (don't some browsers attach focus automatically to the first input on load)?

Comment: I didn't see any change when testing with multiple textfields.  You can add an additional textfield and then update the webdriver code to return the second textfield, and it still didn't pick up as having focus.